# Custom TFS Web Application not working on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, tfs

I have created a web application for user authentication on TFS. I use this piece of code

```
var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(server uri, new NetworkCredential("", ""), new UICredentialsProvider());
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

and it's supposed to bring a new windows log in window.
On visual studio works fine but when I put it in IIS nothing happens.

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I finally got my answer directly from Microsoft. I post it to help the  next poor guy that will try the same thing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/a2e82d36-cfa0-4c45-8710-2cfe30ba1bb9/#b39bc3f6-4740-4cad-8341-fae4b0fbda43

Comment: Please also check that answer as the accepted answer so others can find it.